How to squash SQL migration files into one
Some libraries (e.g. rubenv/sql-migrate) use raw SQL migrations to handle DB changing in time process.
Usually there are some SQL files with DDL/DML commands. The files marked as "Up" contain new changes, and marked as "Down" contain commands to rollback appropriate changes respectively.
So if we have several SQL files e.g.:
000001_0_create_users_table_up.sql
000001_1_create_users_table_down.sql
000002_0_seeding_users_table_up.sql
000002_1_seeding_users_table_down.sql
000003_0_alter_users_table_up.sql
000003_1_alter_users_table_down.sql

assuming they contain SQL commands to change DB, how to merge them to one final file without being linked to a programming language or framework?
As you can see, we can get order of files application, but we always mention that only UP commands was applied.
Example of contents:
-- +migrate Up
-- SQL in section 'Up' is executed when this migration is applied
CREATE TABLE people (id int);


-- +migrate Down
-- SQL section 'Down' is executed when this migration is rolled back
DROP TABLE people;


What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Without knowing what these files contains or how they are applied, it's impossible to provide help

@NicoHaase files may contain any DDL/DML code on SQL. We talking about well known process - DB migrations. Goal is to create SQL that can by used to create same structure in any other DB.

You could actually run them, and then export the resulting database’s schema.

@Ry- sure, but only UP (not DOWN) and in the native order. Maybe someone can advise CLI script to 'cat' files in such way?

Please add all clarification** to your question by editing it. What keeps you from merging all UP files into a single one in "the native order"? Finding any tool for this is off-topic on StackOverflow

SQL migration files with .sql extensions are typically regular text files and there is nothing stopping you from simply combining them:
On Linux/Mac:
cat file1.sql file2.sql > file3.sql

On Windows:
copy /b file1.sql + file2.sql file3.sql

It’s worth noting that we tend to keep migrations isolated so they can be applied incrementally.
Also, you obviously shouldn’t merge up and down together.
